# OleDbException was unhandled

Tags: was, unhandled, oledbexception

I'm using Access as database, but it seems the `OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` throws the error:

> OleDbException was unhandled

[image]

Comment: Can you please use `Copy exception detail to clipboard` and post the details here? It should have more information on what a particular problem is

Comment: Greetings to [little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)!